# Rails: GET and POST routes for the same path causes ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When I visit `/contact`, I get:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
app/controllers/contact_controller.rb:6:in `send'
```

Here are the contents of `config/routes.rb`:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'home#index'  
  get  'contact', to: 'contact#index'
  post 'contact', to: 'contact#send'
end
```

Does including a route for both `get` and `post` for the same path cause the `get` to not be used? `ContactController` has empty actions for `index` and `send` but `index` seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that Rails uses [`Object#send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) to call controller methods by name but you have your own `send` method. Deep inside the Rails routing system it knows that it should route `GET /contact` to a method whose name is the the string `'index'`; the code for that will look sort of like this:

```
controller_instance = an_instance_of_ContactController_from_somewhere
controller_method   = 'index' # This string will be extracted from the `get 'contact', to: '...'` call in routes.rb

controller_instance.send(controller_method)
```

You should be able to rename your `send` method to something else, update your `routes.rb`, and everything should be okay; for example:

```
post 'contact', to: 'contact#send_message'
```

and then in `contact_controller.rb`:

```
def send_message
  #...
end
```

Comment: Very astute observation. This would have taken quite some time to determine since it is an internal implementation concern that, TBH, probably shouldn't occur, especially given the fact that `__send__` is also available.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks but it isn't much of a jump from "string to method call" (a fundamental part of Rails routing) and "there is a method named `send`" to an override problem. Looks like `#send` is used a lot more than `#__send__` in Rails with `__send__` apparently being in newer code.